# Electron and Proton under same voltage

Tags: charge, voltage

What happens when I apply the same voltage to an electron and similarly a proton ? 
Will they have the same kintetic energy ? 
Will they have the same De Brogie wavelength ?

Comment: They will be accelerated in opposite directions.

Answer (score 1):

Neglecting relativity, the de Broglie wavelength is given by $\lambda = \frac{h}{mv}$. Since the proton and electron have different masses, they will not have the same de Broglie wavelength. The field will do the same amount of work to each particle, and therefore impart the same amount of kinetic energy (even though they will have different velocities), but since they have different masses they will have different momenta, and therefore different de Broglie wavelengths.

Comment: Wait, the electron and proton have the same charge, so won't the electric field do the same amount of work to each of them?

Comment: My bad - updated.